# Previously tracked frames are changing

Tags: camera, tracking

I've been experimenting with tracking some footage. I've been advancing the video one frame at a time and setting each frame individually to get a really solid track. However it seems that after a while, previous frames that had my marker dead center in the tracker have begun to slide around. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the codec used in the video?

Comment: see if this post helps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35220/camera-track-was-good-but-breaks-after-editing-an-object/35229#35229