# Frames Dropped During Motion Tracking

Tags: animation, camera, compositing-nodes, video, tracking

I'm having a really frustrating problem with camera motion tracking. Every time I reopen my save, (Tracking points on a video [an MTS file] to composite an object on the video) frames keep getting dropped and it results in my tracking points not syncing up with the video anymore. Is there any way I can resolve this problem? I've tried reloading the MTS file, but the frames are still dropped.

EDIT*
I'm not 100% sure it's frame dropping, but there are frames in which the typical grey checkerboard background is in place where exsting frames should be. Also, the video originally starts at 1 and ends at 2248, but now it starts at 3 and ends at 2250. So it seems like there's frames missing, as well as the entire video shifting by two frames.

Comment: Sounds like a decoding issue. I'd suggest convert the mts file into an image sequence before.

Comment: MTS with long GOP is a terrible format for editing or any kind of postproduction...  Try exporting your video as an image sequence and do the tracking on that. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35220/camera-track-was-good-but-breaks-after-editing-an-object/35229#35229