# video material displays incorrect frames

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, video

I'm following a lightsaber tutorial.

A video is loaded as an image texture material to a plane that then is set to always face the user/camera. A plane with a emission material is created and then I go frame by frame to line it up or use motion tracking with a stick I'm holding in the video.(I'm trying both just for fun.) The problem is that the video frames are changing position with around 1 or 2 frames ahead or after at random.(So I can't just change the video offset.)

When loading the video into a movie clip editor the video lines up correctly. The video cant be loaded as a background video because this removes the emmision from the saber.

I'm rendering in EEVEE. The video is set to auto update the video frame when a new frame is selected.I set the frame count high for the video (around 6000, later 2000 but did no difference). Tell me if you need any more information.

Comment: If the keyframes move when you are not looking, then don't turn away from them... I suggest you change "tutorial" and watch one on motion traking, so that you don't have to manually set the position everytime. It is possible that you are having issues with the way the video is encoded, and that would cause blender to read the wrong frame of the video. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185251/render-is-duplicating-random-frames-when-loaded-into-3d-tracker/185253#185253

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162362/is-it-required-converting-videos-to-an-image-sequence-before-doing-motion-tracki/162364#162364